# how to access or use name in class ? Python

Tags: python-3.x, function, class, namespaces

Python Masters.
I am so curious about class name space.
for example, there some class definition.

```
import Another_class

class Some_class:
    def __init__(self, city):
        self.city = city
        if self.city == "newyork":
            newyork_info = Another_class(some_param)

    def state(self):
        if self.city == "newyork":
           newyork_wether = newyork_info.get_wether()  
           newyork_population = newyork_info.get_population()
```

so, i tend to use "newyork_info" in another functions.

> NameError: name 'newyork_info' is not defined

but i could not use the name in **init** function.
how could i solve it? Is there are good way? :)

Comment: `self.newyork_info = Another_class(some_param)`?

Comment: that works! thank AChampion! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must assign `newyork_info` to the class.

```
self.newyork_info = Another_class(some_param)
```

Comment: Yeh! Thanks a lot! very helpful :)